# Sending message from BOT framework composer published on teams

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have created one **Chatbot using Bot Framework Composer v2.1** .Also Implemented **Oauth Authentication** mechanism so it will ask for login on startup. I published this bot on Teams App. There is a separate azure function running in background for processing. on completion from azure function, I want to send the message to bot that processing is completed. But not able to send messages in Teams. I just wanted to check if there is any provision to send the message to the bot with some URL like directline etc.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a proactive message to send an activity from Azure Function to the bot. For an understanding of what a proactive message is you can reference this BotFramework SDK [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp). In terms of implementing, unfortunately, this link only pertains to writing code-first bots.

Officially, the ability to send a proactive message from BotFramework Composer has never been fully realized with only some underlying code having been developed. Any necessary UI components or how-to docs have yet to be completed.

That being said, there is a workaround. As mentioned in this [post](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/issues/6664#issuecomment-966811257), you can use a custom action to add in the functionality. To do so, you will need to:

- Have Visual Studio on your machine
- Install the [Bot Composer Action](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Vinoth.CustomAction1) VSIX template from the BotBuilder Community
- Open your bot's Composer generated project in Visual Studio
- Follow the instructions posted in this YouTube video, [17 - Proactive Message in Bot Composer (Workaround)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=53pQkc34vpA)
- Profit...?

Now, I'll be transparent and tell you I haven't actually tested this, myself. My understanding from others is it works. Hopefully, this will at least get you pointed in the right direction. Best of luck!